# Complex sorting for Redis on multiple keys. Building Activity Feed

Tags: sql, sorting, redis, schema, nosql

I have a table with columns of data that use in SQL to sort a list of events by Id.  We use this to show activity feeds of these events on our site but would like to move all this to redis.  We've been over the many ways to do something like this, but I want to bounce them off the community here to get some feed back.  Here is the current colum.

[image]

There will be another hash table with all the events data in it for sure.  However where things get sticky is the timing, and mulitple sorts needed.  The first issue is that event in our system are both future, current, and past.  So we need to be able to sort by taking the current time and seeing what is happing now, in the future, and already done.  However on top of that we have other colums to sort by as well.  The multi sorting is where things really get hairy.  Here are some of the multi sorts:

Is Feature? (boolean) = Is it a featured event, if so it should display at the top of our feed regardless of time.

Is it happening now? (unixtimestamp) = Check against current time and get list of all things going on now and list IDs.

Is it in the past?  (unixtimestamp) = Check current time to see if its already done and list IDs

Is it in the future (unixtimestamp) = Check current time to see if its happening later and list IDs

Things get even more crazy when you take into account that events belong to other users.  So we also have to take these ideas and filter them out by USER ID and then sort them.  We dont like the idea of having thousands of sorted sets for each user either.  So how would you guys go about a complex stream like this?

Answer (score 2):

Visualizing relational data in Redis is not straight forward. Like in the example in discussion storing data with different sorting options is a challenge. Solution possible might not look efficient at 1st instance but performance testing should be done to arrive on some final conclusion.

My suggestion for implementing such solution would:

Every column should be mapped to a LIST in Redis. LIST is selected because duplicate entries are possible, else SET can be used.

In above example we can have following LISTs:

ID, ACTIVITY_TYPE, ACTIVITY_ID, LISTING_TYPE, LISTING_ID, IS_PUBLIC, CREATED_AT, UPDATED_AT, ACTIVITY_AT

DATA IS STORED in these lists in following manner:

```
   //first row
   //Column ID
   $ redis-cli lpush ID 10730268
   1

   //If we want to search by ID then create a separate HASH for ID
   $ redis-cli HSET ID_HASH 10730268 1
   1

   //If we want to search by sorted ID then create a separate LIST which stores IDs
   $ redis-cli lpush SORTED_ID 10730268

   //Column ACTIVITY_TYPE
   $ redis-cli lpush ACTIVITY_TYPE "created_event_highlight"
   1

   //Column ACTIVITY_ID
   $ redis-cli lpush ACTIVITY_ID 707003
   1

   //Column LISTING_TYPE
   $ redis-cli lpush LISTING_TYPE "CHANNEL"
   1

   //Column LISTING_ID
   $ redis-cli lpush LISTING_ID 51670
   1

   //Column IS_PUBLIC
   $ redis-cli lpush IS_PUBLIC 1
   1

   //Column CREATED_AT
   $ redis-cli lpush CREATED_AT "2013-04-21 13:34:09"
   1

   //If we want to search by sorted CREATED_AT then create a separate 
   //LIST which maintains for CREATED_AT
   $ redis-cli lpush SORTED_CREATED_AT "2013-04-21 13:34:09"
   1
   //If we want to search by CREATED_AT then create a separate HASH
   $ redis-cli HSET CREATED_AT_HASH "2013-04-21 13:34:09" 1
   1
   //Column UPDATED_AT
   $ redis-cli lpush UPDATED_AT "2013-04-02 11:34:09"
   1

   //Column ACTIVITY_AT
   $ redis-cli lpush ACTIVITY_AT "2014-01-01 03:04:01"
   1
```

The HASH ID_HASH is used to search data using ID as KEY. If data is to be retrieved using SORTED ID's then, SORTED_ID list could be sort using SORT command. ID_HASH could be searched for getting index using sorted IDs returned from SORTED_ID. Using this INDEX we can get values of all the columns.

```
   To fetch data you can do something like :
   $ redis-cli hget ID_HASH 10730268 
    1

   Using these to values as index query columns as
   $redis-cli lindex ID 1
   10730268 

   $redis-cli lindex ACTIVITY_TYPE 1
   "created_event_highlight"
   $redis-cli lindex ACTIVITY_ID 1
   707003
   $redis-cli lindex LISTING_TYPE 1
   "CHANNEL
   $redis-cli lindex IS_PUBLIC 1
    1
  $redis-cli lindex CREATED_AT 1
   "2013-04-21 13:34:09"
  $redis-cli lindex UPDATED_AT 1
   "2013-04-02 11:34:09"
  $redis-cli lindex ACTIVITY_AT 1
   "2014-01-01 03:04:01"
```

Similarly if data is to be retrieved using SORTED CREATED_AT then, SORTED_CREATED_AT list could be sort using SORT command. CREATED_AT returned could be searched in HASH CREATED_AT_HASH for getting index. Using this INDEX we can get values of all the columns. This is assuming id time-stamps are unique. If time-stamps are common then we would have to create separate LISTS for each time-stamps and store all Indexes mapped to a time-stamp.

Other approach  you could take is map your data to be stored to a datastructre and create its objects. Store these created objects in serialized string form in REDIS against IDs or timestamps.

There does not exist a straight forward way for mapping relational databases to REDIS. May be you could explore other NoSql options. But if REDIS is your then try above approaches or innovate using possible data structures(string, list, set, hash) in REDIS.

===========================================

**SERIALIZED OBJECTS**

Considering issues that above solution would have, creating a datatstructre which maps the given data and storing them in string serialized format against different keys seems more reasonable.

(An example of C++ struct)

```
 struct EventInformation{
   friend class boost::serialization::access;

    long id;          //Primary key, you could have primary key as 
                      //combination of members, accordingly KEY in 
                      //HASH TABLE and values being stored in LISTS would change 
    long activityId;
    long listingId;
    bool isPublic;
    std::string activityType;
    std::string listingType;
    std::string createdAt;
    std::string updatedAt;
    std::string activityAt;

    template<class Archive>
      void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version){

       ar & id
          & activityId
          & listingId
          & isPublic
          & activityType
          & listingType
          & createdAt
          & updatedAt
          & activityAt; 
 };
```

- In REDIS we can store the serialized object of above struct against ID in a HASH table.
- Create a separate LISTS for CREATED_AT (i.e. the name of LIST would be like "2013-04-21 13:34:09")  which store LIST of IDs which are mapped to them. This means if there are n timestamps we will have n LISTS.

```
       //created at: we append string "created" in beginning of
       //List names to segregate UPDATE, CREATE and ACTIVITY,
       //although in given example all timestamps are same for a single row
       //I think they might be different as well hence the addition of string literal

       $ redis-cli lpush "created-2013-04-21 13:34:09"  10730268    
       $ redis-cli lpush "created-2013-04-21 13:34:09"  10730267    
       $ redis-cli lpush "created-2013-04-21 13:40:26"  10730266     
       $ redis-cli lpush "created-2013-04-21 13:40:26"  10730265    
       $ redis-cli lpush "created-2013-04-21 13:38:41"  10730264       
       $ redis-cli lpush "created-2013-04-21 13:38:41"  10730263
```

- All the names of CREATED_AT timestamp LIST are stored in master LIST called CREATED_AT_LIST. This enables us to sort the CREATED_AT timetstamps.

```
       $ redis-cli lpush CREATED_AT_LIST "2013-08-23 09:34:09"
       $ redis-cli lpush CREATED_AT_LIST "2013-08-23 09:34:09"
       $ redis-cli lpush CREATED_AT_LIST "2013-08-23 09:40:26"
       $ redis-cli lpush CREATED_AT_LIST "2013-08-23 09:40:26"
       $ redis-cli lpush CREATED_AT_LIST "2013-08-23 09:38:41"
       $ redis-cli lpush CREATED_AT_LIST "2013-08-23 09:38:41"

      Above LIST has to be retrieved in client code and strings have to be converted to
      time format and then sort.
```

Similarly LISTS of UPDATED_AT and ACTIVITY_AT could be created which will have LIST of IDs which are mapped to them. Also their master lists created.

```
   //update at
   $ redis-cli lpush "updated-2013-04-21 09:44:19"  10730268    
   $ redis-cli lpush "updated-2013-04-21 09:44:19"  10730267    
   $ redis-cli lpush "updated-2013-04-21 09:40:26"  10730266    

   $ redis-cli lpush UPDATED_AT_LIST "2013-08-23 09:44:19"
   $ redis-cli lpush UPDATED_AT_LIST "2013-08-23 09:44:19"
   $ redis-cli lpush UPDATED_AT_LIST "2013-08-23 09:40:26"

   //activity at 
   $ redis-cli lpush "activity-2013-04-21 09:44:19"  10730265    
   $ redis-cli lpush "activity-2013-04-21 09:44:19"  10730264       
   $ redis-cli lpush "activity-2013-04-21 09:40:26"  10730263


   $ redis-cli lpush ACTIVITY_AT_LIST "2013-08-23 09:44:19"
   $ redis-cli lpush ACTIVITY_AT_LIST "2013-08-23 09:44:19"
   $ redis-cli lpush ACTIVITY_AT_LIST "2013-08-23 09:40:26"
```

The master lists created could be sorted and ID could be retrieved accordingly. Once we have the ID we can query the HASH table to get back the serialized object which could be de-serialized.

I would try adding a working example of above.

Comment: Thanks for this Nik.  It feels like redis gives the impression of simplicity at face value because it has no schema, but all that loose data starts to hurt my brain when we get into complex sorting that is trivial in SQL.  I'll try to wrap my brain around all this and see how it goes.  It seems like the hardest part is going to be keeping track of time as its constantly moving so the list needs to change.  We need to always know if its past, present, or future.  Great post though

Comment: @Mr.BigglesWorth Yes in this context REDIS is difficult to use. But as we always say every language, every technology is there to solve a purpose. REDIS a KEY-VALUE datastore is not designed on the lines of RDMS. It has its own pros and cons. With available data structures one could design applications to achieve high throughput. COLUMN, DOCUMENT NoSQL options could be explored for resolving above problem.

Comment: I do have positive results using REDIS in my project.

Comment: Makes sense.  The sole reason for our choice in redis is the amazing performance and scalability offered for seemingly simple things like Activity feeds.  

One thing I'm a bit confused about in your example however is how I would sort based off something like is_featured which is a Boolean.  I see that you have the column set up as lpush IS_FEATURED 1.  How would I be able does this actually work with all of the sorts including the time?

For example in SLQ I would first get the current unix time stamp and then ask SQL for everything before the current time to get a list of prior events...

Comment: ...I could then just simply say SELECT * FROM `db` WHERE `start_at` <= unixtimestamp AND `is_featured` = 1.  Since that time is always moving forward this complicates everything further.

Comment: Yes you are right regarding IS_PUBLIC, this solution will not work for IS_PUBLIC which has value 0 or 1.  To have data listed as per IS_PUBLIC we would need to create a separate LIST for IS_PUBLIC_1 and IS_PUBLIC_0 which will store indexes.

Comment: I have edited my solution, hope that is of any help.

Comment: this makes a lot more sense i think.  Put more on the client side, but i think Im better off that way